# Electron js / inter-process communication to initialize an app

Tags: electron

I would like to know the best practice to initialize an Electron app.
I decided to manage the configuration on the main side.
I have a class that load the config.json file with all the methods to get properties.
I have doubts about the flow to populate the renderer view with data.
Here my thoughts:

1. renderer (function) -> preload (invoke) -> main (handle) -> return to preload -> return to renderer
2. main (webContents.send) -> preload.on(callback) -> renderer (callback)

Is there any other better way to do that?
Is it correct to have all the config on the main side?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the main process to initialise your application is the correct way to go.

Prior to creating your main window, you can initialise your configuration module and `get` the applications configuration data.

Next, create your main window with [new BrowserWindow()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) but set the  `show` option to `false`. EG: `show: false`. This will hide the window.

Next, use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)  to communicate **from** your main process **to** your render process any  configuration data necessary to correctly set-up the content of your render. IE: Send from the main process: [send(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) and receive in the render process: [ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener).

Finally, `show()` your window.

This is the flow I have used in the past and it works well.

Additionally, if you have a 'configuration' window where you can make application setting changes:

1. [Render Process] - Communicate the individual change via IPC to the main process.
2. [Main Process] - Have your main process configuration module update the specific in-memory configuration object value.
3. [Main Process] - [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the configuration object and (re)write it over the current (`config.json`) file.
4. [Main Process] - Communicate the **updated** configuration object via IPC to the render process.
5. [Render Process] - Listen for and when received, update any content via the use of a render side configuration module.

I prefer the above process because:

1. The render process should only be used to render content. Anything other may slow down or freeze the render process.
2. The main process can handle the heavy lifting such as updating the (configuration) object, (re)writing files, etc.
3. Simple logic is kept in the render, such as the detection and transmission of UI events back to the main process and repainting content when requested to do so by the main process.
4. Finally, should your UI update after a settings change, you know the whole process is working correctly.

I use the above technique for not only setting (configuration) changes but to remember user customisation of the UI such as columns widths and ordering, showing or hiding panels, selection and ordering of favourite items, etc.

Comment: I see there is the "did-finish-load" event to use in main to trigger the send. Is it correct  to use that instead of the show:false settings?

Comment: @somtam You could use either method depending on your requirements. If you are loading a local file (window) and your initial configuration process is expected to take some time, you could instead initially show a splash window or a frameless transparent window with a loading spinner. Once the main window has been rendered correctly, then you could destroy the initial window and `show` the main window. Alternatively, use of the `did-finish-load` event is an acceptable approach if rendering a URL and not a local file.